# I'm facing an issue in my wordpress my listing theme,It is giving datatables ajax load error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

The listing theme is displaying the list of reviews of customers, On the site, the user can add a comment, and on the admin side when approved by the admin the list will be displayed in the approved listings. The theme tables are using the data tables library, which is giving an ajax error, I'm attaching the error pictures. Below

[image]

[image]

[image]
This error occurs when I click on the unapproved lists, demo data of the theme is showing in the lists, but new data is not displaying.

The same theme configurations are on my localhost and everything is working. But on the online server, it is not working.

The solution I tried "https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7" , but I don't know where to put
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw'; this line in Wordpress directory

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? As you haven't shared any code, it's pretty dififcult to provide help

Comment: I'm using wordpress, and I haven't coded anything, everything is pre-built, I only installed the theme and imported the demo content.                                                                                  The solution I tried "https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7"  in this link they have mentioned that to put jquery code line "$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';", but they haven't mentioned where to put this line of code in order to remove this error